# Total amount of close votes displayed twice

Tags: bug, status-completed

Theres been some new changes to the way the vote to close system works. Rather than showing just the total close votes like before as a whole number it shows it as (x/5) where x is the amount of votes.

The issue i just noticed is this, i went to a question and it was 3/5 i added my vote and instead of diaplaying 4/5 it displayed (3/5)(4/5), i had to refresh the page to get it to display just (4/5). (screen shot on the way)

Its nothing major, just something i noticed

[image: Double Vote]

Edit: Note, not an isolated incident, easily repeatable

[image]

Comment: Confirmed; investigating. Thanks.

Comment: kinda embarrassed to say it took 3 clicks for me to click on the right "edit" link to mark this as completed... even the giant red boxes wasn't enough for my poor brain to twig

Comment: @MarcGravell when i tried to upload the second picture even i clicked on the wrong one!

Comment: @MarcGravell also, just so youre aware, it also does this with re-open votes too

Comment: I think the same block of code handles all of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks; this will be fixed in the next deploy. It looks like we changed the display from `(3)` to `(3/5)`, but the javascript / regex at the client wasn't updated accordingly.